# Error during a wikidata update

Tags: wikidata, wikidata-api

I've created a local version of the wikidata api using the instructions [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_query_service/User_Manual#Standalone_service), and after running `munge.sh` with the default options, I've run
`./runUpdate.sh -n wdq` which resulted with the following error message.

```
ERROR org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.Update - 
RDF store reports the last update time is before the minimum safe poll time.
You will have to reload from scratch or you might have missing data.
```

What does it mean? Should I `munge` again before updating?

Comment: Probably your RDF dump is outdated, it seems it should be 30 or less days old: https://github.com/wikimedia/wikidata-query-rdf/blob/master/tools/src/main/java/org/wikidata/query/rdf/tool/Update.java#L176

Comment: Thanks, so I should download a new dump and start from scratch? Also, please consider writing your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Assuming your dump is dated on 2017-08-01, probably you could set system date to 2017-08-20 and run `runUpdate.sh`, then set system time to the current time and run this script again...

Comment: Thanks, I keep getting `HTTP request failed: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused` but perhaps that's a different issue.

Comment: Probably connection refusion is not a different issue, but HTTPS handshake (or something like) problem, when setting client date to 2017-08-20... Then probably you should start from skratch :(.

Answer (score 1):

The default updater can only currently update based on what is in RecentChanges for the wiki.
The default for this is 30 days, so if the dump that you imported is from longer than 30 days ago the updater will fail.

There are options that can now be passed to the updater script to look into the history of RecentChanges for longer periods.
You can also set the last updater triple that the check is performed on.

These options can be seen discussed in https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T182394 (but im not sure better docs currently exist):

- "wikibaseMaxDaysBack" can be used to set the maximum days to look back in RecentChanges
- "init" can be used to set the last updated triple